# Java special array top up/overwrite

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to up above defined array. It stores points with its coordinates.

```
public static List<Edge> simpleGraph(List<Point> nodes) {
    int numEdges = nodes.size() * 2;
    List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>(numEdges);
    for (int i = 0; i < numEdges; i++) {
        Point p1 = nodes.get((int) (Math.random() * nodes.size()));
        Point p2 = nodes.get((int) (Math.random() * nodes.size()));
        edges.add(new Edge(p1, p2));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        Edge e = edges.get(i);
        if (e.p1.equals(e.p2))
            edges.remove(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        Edge e = edges.get(i);
        for (int q = 0; q < edges.size(); q++) {
            if (i == q)
                continue;
            Edge e2 = edges.get(q);
            if (e.equals(e2))
                edges.remove(q);
        }
    }

    return edges;
}
```

I have a fixed number of elements in an integer list and want to overwrite original(above generated) integers with my own values from my list.

Values are accessible in this way:

```
System.out.println (
   "x1 " + e.p1.x + "  y1 " + e.p1.y + 
    "   x2 " + e.p2.x + "   y2 " + e.p2.y
);
```

I have tried to use a simple `for` iteration, but overwrite every values more than once.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you want to replace the values in a list, clear it and put the new values in it.

Comment: It not a "simple" list, I cannot get elements directly.

Comment: So please explain better what you want. It's not clear what the connection is between the edge list that your code produces and the integers that you want to replace. Give an example of the two lists and what you want to happen.

Comment: e.p1.x: 71 e.p1.y: 108   e.p2.x: 397   e.p2.y 36

(Who cannot know solution, will put in hold this, as usual. :D)

Comment: **Edit your question**, don't write information in comments. Give *details*. What is the list you want to change? What is the list of points? What do you want the result to look like? What is the simple `for` loop you tried? The question will be put on hold not because "people cannot know solution", but because you are not asking properly.

Comment: All that I know, that above "list's" elements should be replaced by another integer list. But I cannot do this with a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you want to replace coordinates of every point of every edge. Those coordinates are stored in List.

```java
List<Integer> myCoordinates; 

// initalize myCoordinates so it has  
// edges.size()*points_per_edge*coordinates_per_point elements
// = edges.size() * 2 * 2 in your case

for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
   int j = i*4;
   Edge edge = edges.get(i);
   edge.p1.x = myCoordinates.get(j);
   edge.p1.y = myCoordinates.get(j+1);
   edge.p2.x = myCoordinates.get(j+2);
   edge.p2.y = myCoordinates.get(j+3);
}
```

Comment: Why should I use `get()` for edges? It is empty at this time.